# How to convert frm and ibd files to sql format?

Tags: mysql

I installed cyberpanel using vps in hostinger. I made some errors in updating cyberpanel, which caused the VPS server to crash and couldn't enter. Finally, I turned on Emergency Mode in the hostinger VPS and downloaded the data of the website as a backup, but I couldn't After downloading the database data, in the end I only found frm and ibd files in /mnt/var/lib/mysql/, now how should I restore the database data?

Comment: Can you get your VPS, in emergency mode, to run the MySQL server? If so you can use mysqldump to get your data. Ask your support person. Restoring data from ibd and frm files is a last resort.

Comment: I tried installing mysql and running, but both show (no package musql-server available)(unit mysql.service could not be found)

Comment: If I rebuild a new vps, upload the script of the website again, and then recreate the database with the same name, then I enable emergency mode, replace the data in /mnt/var/lib/mysql/ with the previous frm and idb file, will this work?

Comment: If you rebuild the same VPS - yes, it will work.